# Using it.buildConfigField for string resources flavors

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-productflavors

I try to build Andoird SettingsLib module with Android 3.3.2
In this module strings.xml files there are duplicated resources like:

```
<!-- [CHAR_LIMIT=50] Short label for imminent shutdown warning of device -->
<string name="power_remaining_duration_only_shutdown_imminent" product="default">Phone may shutdown soon</string>
<!-- [CHAR_LIMIT=50] Short label for imminent shutdown warning of device -->
<string name="power_remaining_duration_only_shutdown_imminent" product="tablet">Tablet may shutdown soon</string>
<!-- [CHAR_LIMIT=50] Short label for imminent shutdown warning of device -->
<string name="power_remaining_duration_only_shutdown_imminent" product="device">Device may shutdown soon</string>
```

I have the feeling this is in order to manager different product flavours (terminal case in that case).

Is I simply build the code without any modifications I get multiplied defined resources like:

> Error: Found item String/power_remaining_duration_only_shutdown_imminent more than one time

I started to try to solve this issue and I read some pages abour Android flavours.

I added flavors to my app `build.gradle` file that looks like this now:

```
    flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    device {
        applicationId
        "com.ebookfrenzy.buildexample.app.phone"
        versionName "1.0-phone"
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField ("string","product","device")
        }
    }
    tablet {
        applicationId
        "com.ebookfrenzy.buildexample.app.tablet"
        versionName "1.0-tablet"
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField ("string","product","default")
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId
        "com.ebookfrenzy.buildexample.app.default"
        versionName "1.0-tablet"
        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField ("string","product","default")
        }
    }
}
```

But this did not solve my error.

How can I paramteter my byuild with flavors in order to setect only one multiply defined resource during one build?